# Making SUM function work with derived types

Tags: fortran

I have a user type which contains two or more arrays of different sizes.

```
type state    
    real(real64) :: pos(3), ori(4), vee(3), omg(3)
end type
```

and I have defined the `(*)` and `(+)` operators in order to be able to do algebra

```
interface operator (+)
    procedure st_add
end interface
interface operator (*)
    procedure st_scale1, st_scale2
end interface

contains

elemental function st_add(a,b) result(c)
type(state), intent(in) :: a,b
type(state) :: c
    c = state( &
        a%pos + b%pos, &
        a%ori + b%ori, &
        a%vee + b%vee, &
        a%omg + b%omg)
    
end function

elemental function st_scale1(a,b) result(c)
real(real64), intent(in) :: a
type(state), intent(in) :: b
type(state) :: c

    c = state( &
        a * b%pos, &
        a * b%ori, &
        a * b%vee, &
        a * b%omg)
    
end function

elemental function st_scale2(b,a) result(c)
real(real64), intent(in) :: a
type(state), intent(in) :: b
type(state) :: c

    c = state( &
        a * b%pos, &
        a * b%ori, &
        a * b%vee, &
        a * b%omg)
    
end function
```

now I am using the above in a linear algebra operation such as

```
    real(real64), parameter :: c(4) = [1/6d0, 2/6d0, 2/6d0, 1/6d0]        
    type(state) :: k(4),k_step

    k_step = c(1)*k(1)+c(2)*k(2)+c(3)*k(3)+c(4)*k(4)
```

but what I want for brevity and code flexibility to use the following

```
    k_step = sum( c(:)*k(:) )    ! error
```

which results in the following error **`error #6362: The data types of the argument(s) are invalid.   [SUM]`**.

So what are my options? Do I need an generic interface for `sum` calling `st_add`? Or do I need some other definition?

<sub>I am using Intel® Fortran Compiler Classic 2021.1.2 (part of oneAPI HPC).</sub>

---

#### Solution

The solution that worked best is to add the following

```
interface sum
    procedure st_sum
end interface

contains

pure function st_sum(a) result (s)
type(state), intent(in) :: a(:)
type(state) :: s
integer :: i, n
    n = size(a)        
    s = a(1)
    do i=2, n
        s = s + a(i)
    end do
end function
```

and usage

```
k_step = sum(c(:)*k(:))
st = this + h*k_step
```

Well, I actually I combined the two statements above into one

```
st = this + sum( (h*c(:))*k(:) )
```

Overall I get the same results, but with a slight performance penalty (about 10%). It must be all that array copying values for function results. IDK.

Comment: BTW, I recommend just writing `c*k` instead, see https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/doctor-it-hurts-when-i-do-this.html

Comment: @VladimirF I was reading (https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/explicit-vector-programming-in-fortran.html) which in the notes uses `c(:)*k(:)` type notation. I will try both

Comment: I'd be tempted to write a `dot_product` type function taking two array arguments rather than evaluating an expression which is array-times-array.  It may not be faster, but it'd certainly clear up whether the array temporary is hurting performance.

Comment: Good idea. `(array of scalar) × (array of composite) = sum(array of scalar×composite)` type of function.I think this is what you are proposing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Do I need an generic interface for sum calling st_add?*

You do need to add a specific function to the `sum` generic interface. It does not matter that much what exactly that function calls internally. It must be a function that works for the `state` type arrays, that is important.

```
interface sum
  procedure your_function
end interface


function your_function(a)
   type(state) :: your_function
   type(state), intent(in) :: a(:)
   ...
end function
```

Comment: Thank you V. Based on your answer I implement my solution (see edit in question). Do you have a comment on performance penalty when using `sum()` vs. the "unrolled" version of `c(1)*k(1) + c(2)*k(2) + ..`

Comment: @JAlex I cannot comment on the performance in any way, compiler optimizers are very smart. You have to test. A temporary array may indeed bring some performance penalty.

Answer (score 3):

A user-defined specific procedure for the generic `operator(+)` does not (and should not) imply an implementation for `sum`.  If you wish to provide a specific procedure for the generic `sum` then you will have to provide one yourself.

In Fortran, the intrinsic `sum` (for intrinsic numeric types) is not defined in terms of `+` so there is no natural analogue for derived types.

Similarly, `product` and `norm2` are not defined in terms of `*` and `+`.

The question seems to like the idea of `dot_product`.  Although this function *is* defined in terms of `*` (and `sum`) this isn't useful: the intrinsic function takes only intrinsic types and doesn't consider specific procedures for `sum` and `operator(*)`.

Comment: Nice to know that `dot_prodct` uses `(*)` and thanks for the info.